# Баг при использовании "transform: scale();"

Tags: css, css-animation, transform

При наведении на блок он должен увеличиваться и текст внутри него, соответственно, что собственно и происходит. Хром отображает все корректно, а вот мазила - нет. В мазиле наблюдается такой баг, что текст начинает немного дергаться, когда изменяет свой размер. Понятно, что это все происходит из-за пикселизации и из-за нецелого коэффициента увеличения.

https://jsfiddle.net/2xmhadnu/13/

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5em auto;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 12rem;
  -webkit-transition: transform .2s;
  -moz-transition: transform .2s;
  -ms-transition: transform .2s;
  -o-transition: transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s;
  will-change: transform;
}

div > p{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}

div:hover{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Text in block</p>
</div>
```

Буду благодарен тем, кто подскажет, как убрать этот дергающийся эффект и заставить мазилу отображать все корректно.

Comment: Скорее всего никак

Comment: Всегда есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/709387/edit) :)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте, запретить отображать скрытые части скейлящегося объекта:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Большинство дерганий при скейлинге это лечит.

Comment: Читал об этом решении на просторах интернета, но все равно результат тот же: текст по-прежнему дергается

Comment: Подтверждаю, не помогает

Answer (score 1):

подними will-change: transform; выше строчки transition: transform .2s;

что бы он читал  will-change  должен прочитать раньше и еще

div:hover
добавь
  transition: transform .2s;

и будет как надо

Comment: Нет, не помогает. Вы сами-то пробовали сделать и проверить всё что написали?

Comment: Если вы не заметили, я не автор вопроса :) Проблема не в том, что тормозит (оно ведь не тормозит), а в том, что текст дергается, и дергается он и в вопросе, и во всех ответах, включая ваш

Comment: Порядок свойств вообще не должен влиять.

Comment: will-change: transform; все-таки помогает, но все равно работает не так гладко как в Хроме

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать вместе со скейлом транслейтЗед
transform: scale(1.5) translateZ(0);

Похожая проблема описана здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391507/transform-scale-firefox-text-issue

UPD: проблема должна решиться, потому что translateZ запускает в браузере аппаратное ускорение анимации, что благоприятно влияет на ее отображение

Comment: У меня как-то не помогает

Comment: Сейчас еще хуже, ускорился отдельное движение текста

Comment: Тоже не работает

Comment: scale () тоже использует аппаратное ускорение

Answer (score 0):

В текущей мозиле фиксится через svg filter, но проблема в том, что она в растр текст переводит и она бьется при ресайзе. 
Но можно такой хак применить например:

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5em auto;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 12rem;
  transition: transform .2s;
  will-change: transform;
}

div > p{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;
  transform: scale(.5);
  filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><filter id="gaussian_blur"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" /></filter></defs></svg>#gaussian_blur');
}

div:hover{
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Text in block</p>
</div>
```

Ну и подогнать положение текста под контейнер с учетом скэйла

Comment: Решение хорошее, только никаких изменений я не вижу

Comment: У вас бьется текст? Я пробовал все варианты на своей машине и этот заработал отлично. Лучше чем в хроме плавность.

Comment: Да, все равно бьется

Comment: а у меня идеально та же проблема что и у вастора

Comment: И этот вариант у меня тоже не помогает